# Upgrade Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse, project, adt

With each new version of the Android Developer tools comes new project setups. Is there a way to upgrade old projects to the new format via eclipse or commandline?

I've been doing it manually by creating a new project and diffing the project files.

Comment: Are you talking about project properties or deprecated apis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From command line you can use:

```
android update project -p [project path] -n [project name]
```

See [Updating a Project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html#UpdatingAProject) for more info.